# Install MEncoder on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, mencoder

I installed MEncoder following the answer at [how to install mencoder in ubuntu 14.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595978/how-to-install-mencoder-in-ubuntu-14-10)

But when I use MEncoder, I got the error:

> mencoder: error while loading shared libraries: libswscale.so.2:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It's supposed to work with `libswscale.so.3`. Similarly for other libraries, I have newer version than mencoder looks for. FYI, my gnome MPlayer is 1.0.9. Can anyone help me with it? Thank you very much.